# Typescript "error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x", user "x", database "x", SSL off"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, kubernetes, typeorm

### Setup

I'm currently using Kubernetes to manage my NodeJS services.

Every NodeJS service has its own PostgreSQL database, I'm using TypeORM to access each database. Everything worked fine until I converted my Kubernetes Deployment to a StatefulSet. I did this because I wanted my databases to keep their data, even after being shut down.

### Problem

The NodeJS service (`confirmation-deployment-{unique-id}`) which represents a REST API can't connect to the PostgreSQL database (`confirmation-postgres-statefulset-{number}`)

[image]

### Error

The logs return this error: `error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x", user "x", database "x", SSL off`
[image]

I found that I had to set `{ssl: true}` in my `ConnectionOptions` but when
I did this I got another error: `Error: The server does not support SSL connections`.

[image]

I'm basically stuck at the moment. The first error tells me to convert `{ssl: false}` to `{ssl: true}`, while the other error tells me to do the opposite. I've no idea why this happens, all of this started when I converted the Deployment to a StatefulSet inside Kubernetes.

If I can take a guess, it's perhaps an internal cluster network issue inside Kubernetes? Anyway, I'm not familiar with those errors...

Any help would be appreciated!

### System Information

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop
- Linux Containers

### Code

ormconfig.json: TypeORM's way to define the `ConnectionOptions`.

```
{
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "confirmation-postgres-service",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "12345",
  "database": "postgres",
  "synchronize": true,
  "ssl": false,
  "entities": [
    "src/models/*.model.ts"
  ]
}
```

confirmation-postgres-statefulset.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: confirmation-postgres-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: "confirmation-postgres"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: confirmation-postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: confirmation-postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: confirmation-postgres
          image: postgres
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: confirmation-postgres-config
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
            name: confirmation-db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: confirmation-postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: confirmation-postgres-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: confirmation-postgres-pvc
```

confirmation-postgres-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: confirmation-postgres-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: confirmation-postgres
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

confirmation-postgres-config.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: confirmation-postgres-config
  labels:
    app: confirmation-postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "12345"
```

confirmation-postgres-pv.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: confirmation-postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

confirmation-postgres-pvc.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: confirmation-postgres-pvc
  labels:
    app: confirmation-postgres
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ssl, you need to configure/compiler your PostgreSQL server to support it.

If you don't want to use ssl, you need to configure your pg_hba.conf to allow connections (from that host, user, and database) without ssl.  Most likely your pg_hba.conf just doesn't allow this connection either way (either with or without ssl), but the client is only reporting on the one it actually attempted.  I say this because if you pg_hba demands ssl, but your server doesn't support it, then it should refuse to start in the first place.  And if it didn't start, you would be getting a different error.